# Loop through multiple items in json and assign variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to loop through some json. The json result looks like this:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "metafield1": "May 22 2019"
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": "May 20 2019"
  }]
}
```

I'm getting this in an ajax call that then assigns a variable and then checks if the variable exists.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/cart?view=alternate.json',
  success: function(result) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
    var del_date = obj.metafield1;
    if (del_date !== null) {
      // do something
    }
  }
})
```

At first I only had one item in the json so this worked fine, but now as you can see I've got multiple so I need to loop through them and eventually compare them so basically I need to store each one of them as a variable.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON object though

Comment: If @wentjun says it's not valid, it's because an object cannot have duplicate keys. It's the same in JS where it throws an error in strict mode or ignore the dupes in non-strict

Comment: You have duplicate keys in your JSON.You should modify your JSON keys, or have one key containing an array of values. Then loop through the keys or array

Comment: edited the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working :

```js
// we set a variable x = to your JSON variable
var x = {
  "items": [{
    "metafield1": "May 22 2019"
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": "May 20 2019"
  }]
};

// we update x to be equal to your item field from the object, x is now an array instead of an object
x = x["items"];

for (var i of x) {
  if (i.metafield1 !== null) {
    console.log(i.metafield1);
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your string like this use map function with [] operator

```
var string = '[{ "metafield1": "May 22 2019" } , { "metafield1": null } , 
 { "metafield1": null } , { "metafield1": "May 20 2019" } ]';

var metafields = JSON.parse(string).map(function(v){ return v['metafield1']; });

console.log(metafields);
```

Updated with new object

```
let result = {
  "items": [{
    "metafield1": "May 22 2019"
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": "May 20 2019"
  }]
};

string = JSON.stringify(result.items);

var metafields = JSON.parse(string).map(function(v){ return v['metafield1']; });

console.log(metafields);
```

```js
let result = {
  "items": [{
    "metafield1": "May 22 2019"
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": null
  }, {
    "metafield1": "May 20 2019"
  }]
};
//console.log(JSON.stringify(result.items));

//var string = '[{ "metafield1": "May 22 2019" } , { "metafield1": null } , { "metafield1": null } , { "metafield1": "May 20 2019" } ]';

string = JSON.stringify(result.items);

var metafields = JSON.parse(string).map(function(v){ return v['metafield1']; });

console.log(metafields);
```